# PHP Array with IDs and Description - randomize array and print list

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, shuffle

Since I'm not much of a php guy I need help with creating an array that holds YouTube videos and a description for each video.

Right now I have an array that only holds the video id's. What is the best way to add a Description to each ID so I can easily loop through the array and create the desired output underneath.

```
<?php
    $vids = array(
        "OOWvNbU6ciLg",
        "5itTJabAJfps",
        "jFA8Tesmames",
        "Trz9Y01xx1TY",
        "mMQGcIrlyseU",
        "qGrlQNvqqL14",
        "QymnLbSpJ7lA",
        "jFAh8Tesmmes",
        "5itTJtbAJfps",
        "OOWvNpU6ciLg"
    );
?>
```

What I want eventually is a list of videos with a video description underneath. And I want my array to be shuffled before the list is created so I have a different order each time the list is created.

**HTML**

```
<li class="video">
    <figure>
        <iframe width="100%" height="200px" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/OxXAT2epfEYA?HD=1;rel=0;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <figcaption>Description of the video</figcaption>
    </figugre>
</li>
```

What would be the best way to define the array so I can shuffle it and then loop through the array and print each `<li>` item with the `iframe` embed code and the description underneath.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep all info about video in associative array:

```
$single_video = array(
    "id" => "OOWvNbU6ciLg",
    "description" => "Video descr"
);
```

Now build an array of these videos:

```
$vids = array(
    array(
        "id" => "OOWvNbU6ciLg",
        "description" => "Video descr"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => "5itTJabAJfps",
        "description" => "Other video descr"
    ),
);
```

Now you can shuffle it easily, and loop:

```
$vids = array();
shuffle($vids);
foreach($vids as $video){
    //$video here is associative array with single video
    echo "{$video['id']} - {$video['description']}";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just thinking off the top of my head you could you an associative array by putting the IDs and descriptions together in the array.

```
vidArray = array(
videoId1 => 'This is the description for video 1.',
videoId2 => 'This is the description for video 2',
etc. );
```

You could then use a for each statement to loop through the array and create your iframes using the array elements information.

PHP also has a built in shuffle function to randomly shuffle an array.
[Array shuffle](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)

Comment: But shuffling associative array means losing its keys, so you will not have videoId after shuffling such array.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller Thank you, I didn't know that.  I've never actually come across a situation that needed to use the array shuffle function.  I just remember seeing that it existed while reading through the PHP manual one day.